# Javascript: Find all root integers of a number

Tags: javascript

Just for kicks, I'm trying to write a function that tells me all the roots of a number. I'm not sure on the math terminology, but I want the number and it's power that equals the given number.

For example, given the number 1024 I would get
`{2:10, 4:5, 32:2}` (ie: `2^10 = 4^5 = 32^2 = 1024`).

I actually wrote a working algorithm but it runs into problems with floating point precision and I'm wondering if there's a better way.

This is the function I have now:

```
function findRoots(n) {
    let result = {}
    for (root = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n)); root >= 2; root--) {
        let test = n ** (1 / root)
        if (Number.isInteger(test)) {
            result[test] = root
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

The output is an object where the property names are the roots and the values are the exponents.

But, for example, if I feed it 16807 (which should give me `{7:5}`), I get nothing back because the method I'm using to test roots chokes on the float precision (ie `16807 ** (1/5) == 7.000000000000001`).

Is there a way to deal with the floats besides just lopping off some precision?

Comment: `if(Math.round(test) ** root == n)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
if (Math.round(test) ** root == n) {
```

instead of

```
if (Number.isInteger(test)) {
```

### Proof

[image: test = n^{1/root}]

[image: \Rightarrow {test}^{root} = n]

[image: \Rightarrow round({test})^{root} = n \Leftrightarrow {test} \in N]

Since we use `Math.round(test)`, the roundoff error in `test` will not cause any problems.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let test = +(n ** (1 / root)).toFixed(10)
```

should do the trick

```js
function findRoots(n) {
  let result = {}
  for (root = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n)); root >= 2; root--) {
    let test = +(n ** (1 / root)).toFixed(10)
    if (Number.isInteger(test)) {
      result[test] = root
    }
  }
  return result
}

console.log(findRoots(16807))
```